# remove values from total for certain condition, but not others

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following query:

```
select a.user_id, sum(c.amount) as all_assets, 
sum(case when b.class='x' then c.amount end) assets_x, 
sum(case when b.class='y' then c.amount end) assets_y, 
sum(case when b.class='z' and c.amount<=100 then c.amount end) assets_z
from a
join b on a.id=b.id
join c on b.id=c.id
group by a.user_id
```

This groups assets by user id, and break total assets into classes x, y and z, where class z and only z excludes entrees with `c.amount >100`.

My question is, when calculating all_assets, how can I remove the entrees with `c.amount>100` for `b.class='z'` from the total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this for all parts of the `select`, use a `where` clause:

```
select a.user_id, sum(c.amount) as all_assets, 
       sum(case when b.class = 'x' then c.amount end) as assets_x, 
       sum(case when b.class = 'y' then c.amount end) as assets_y, 
       sum(case when b.class = 'z' and c.amount <= 100 then c.amount end) as assets_z
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id join
     c
     on b.id = c.id
where not (b.class = 'z' and c.amount > 100)
group by a.user_id;
```

You can also phrase this as one more conditional aggregation:

```
select a.user_id,  
       sum(case when b.class in ('x', 'y') or c.amount <= 100 then c.amount end) as all_assets,
       sum(case when b.class = 'x' then c.amount end) as assets_x, 
       sum(case when b.class = 'y' then c.amount end) as assets_y, 
       sum(case when b.class = 'z' and c.amount <= 100 then c.amount end) as assets_z
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id join
     c
     on b.id = c.id
group by a.user_id;
```

This version assumes that the only classes are x, y, and z.

Comment: you meant: where not (b.class = 'z' and c.amount > 100) right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that first bit of code... wouldn't the predicate prevent anything from being returned that would sum into assets_z?

Comment: @SQLCliff I am getting values for assets z returned. The `and c.amount <= 100` seems in `assets_z` seems redundant, and I think it should be `where not (b.class = 'z' and c.amount > 100)` instead of <= but otherwise looks good

Comment: @user8834780 . . . Yes, that is what I mean.  I fixed the logic.